# bulk join json with jpg from Google Takeout

Tags: json, exiftool, google-photos

I wish to leave Google photos, and I have downloaded all my photos using Google Takeout. Now I have a boatload of folders containing both json files (that I think contains exif data) and images. The structure looks like this: home/user/Billeder/Takeout/Google Photos/2011-06-09/file.json.
home/user/Billeder/Takeout(2)/Google Photos/2011-07-09/file.json.

I want to join the json data with the correct images and organize the images in folders that correspond to their creation date.
I have been looking at Exiftool, but all answers found so far only shows how to do this for a single image. What I'm looking for is a way to join all the data with the correct images in bulk.

I'm trying to do this in linux command line.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Exiftool now has the ability to do this as of ver 10.47.

In my testing, I've seen two different formats for the json filename, some where it is `filename.ext.json` and some where it is `filename.json` (no extension in the json filename).  Here are two command to cover either situation.  If you have a mixtures, as I do, run both.

Files with extension in the json filename
`exiftool -tagsfromfile '%d/%F.json' '-ImageTag<JsonTag' FileOrDir`

Files without extension in the json filename
`exiftool -tagsfromfile '%d/%f.json' '-ImageTag<JsonTag' FileOrDir`

Replace `FileOrDir` with the file or directory you wish to process.  Replace `ImageTag` with the name of the tag in the image you want to copy to.  Replace `JsonTag` with the name of the tag from the json file you wish to copy from.  If you are on Windows instead of linux, use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Here are some of the more useful tags that I've encountered in the json file and my suggestions where to copy them.  Two of the tag names, Description and Title, are the same as the related XMP tags, so they don't need to be redirected into the image tag name and can be left simply as `-Description` or `-Title` in the above commands.
**description**: Description of the file.  The appropriate placement for this would be IPTC:Caption-Abstract, XMP:Description, and EXIF:ImageDescription. You could copy these with `'-Caption-Abstract<Description'`, `-Description`, or `'-ImageDescription<Description'`.
**title**: Name of the uploaded file. This can be copied into `Title`, `ObjectDescription` or `PreservedFileName`.
**people**:  Not sure but I'm guessing that if the file has had people tagged in a program such as Picasa, this would be the list of names, most likely from the `RegionPersonDisplayName`.
**url**: This is an URL that the image can be downloaded from.  WARNING: It is a publicly shared URL and even if the image is marked private, it can still be downloaded with this URL.
**GeoInfoAltitude_**, **GeoInfoLatitude_**, and **GeoInfoLongitude_**:  If the uploaded file was geotagged, these will be the Altitude, Latitude, and Longitude for the image.  These would best be copied into `GPSAltitude`, `GPSLatitude`, `GPSLatitudeRef`, `GPSLongitude`, and `GPSLongitudeRef`.  Because of the nature of GPS tags (unsigned), image that are in the Western and/or Southern hemisphere **must** also have the Ref tags set.

Example commands:
Copy gps tags
`exiftool -tagsfromfile '%d/%F.json' '-GPSAltitude<GeoDataAltitude' '-GPSLatitude<GeoDataLatitude' '-GPSLatitudeRef<GeoDataLatitude' '-GPSLongitude<GeoDataLongitude' '-GPSLongitudeRef<GeoDataLongitude' FileOrDir`

Copy Keywords:
`exiftool -tagsfromfile '%d/%F.json' '-Keywords<Tags' '-Subject<Tags' FileOrDir`

Copy Description:
`exiftool -tagsfromfile '%d/%F.json' '-Caption-Abstract<Description' '-ImageDescription<Description' -Description FileOrDir`

Copy all the data from the JSON to the files, modifying the original files (2020):

```sh
exiftool -r -d %s -tagsfromfile "%d/%F.json" "-GPSAltitude<GeoDataAltitude" "-GPSLatitude<GeoDataLatitude" "-GPSLatitudeRef<GeoDataLatitude" "-GPSLongitude<GeoDataLongitude" "-GPSLongitudeRef<GeoDataLongitude" "-Keywords<Tags" "-Subject<Tags" "-Caption-Abstract<Description" "-ImageDescription<Description" "-DateTimeOriginal<PhotoTakenTimeTimestamp" -ext jpg -overwrite_original FileOrDir
```

---

Edit (Jan 2018): As always, Google will change everything.  The above **GeoInfo*** tags are deprecated according to the comment below and have been replaced by **GeoDataAltitude**, **GeoDataLatitude**, and **GeoDataLongitude**.

Edit (Oct 2020): Update commands for 2020 JSON format

Exiftool can read Json files, so if there are other changes, running the command `exiftool -s FILE.Json` will list all the tags and available data that can be copied.

Comment: excellent info, thanks. What happens if the target field already contains info? e.g. can you write only if empty? or perhaps merge? (in case of keywords, wouldn't make sense for GPS)

Comment: Add `-wm CG` to write only if the tag is empty.  To add additional keywords, I think it's `-AddTagsFromFile` instead of `-TagsFromFile` and you put a plus `+` sign in the middle: `-AddTagsFromFile "-Keywords+<JSONTAG"`.  This is one operation I can never remember the exact option.

Comment: Use `-d "%b %d, %Y, %l:%M:%S %p %Z" '-alldates<PhotoTakenTimeFormatted'` to set the photo taken time.

Comment: For what it's worth, I noticed that someone made a dedicated tool for this: https://github.com/mattwilson1024/google-photos-exif

Comment: Given command still works as intended. Thanks! (July 2021)

Comment: I think add this `"-CreateDate<CreationTimeTimestamp" "-ModifyDate<PhotoLastModifiedTimeTimestamp"` is better.

Answer (score 5):

As an update in December 2020, as Pieter mentioned, there is a dedicated tool that took me ~5min to set up: https://github.com/mattwilson1024/google-photos-exif.

However, that doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the other answer (`PHOTO_NAME(1).jpg` being confused with `PHOTO_NAME.jpg(1).json`) as well as timezones. More importantly, none of the answers here overwrite the QuickTime- and PNG-specific tags.

I've found that this software https://metadatafixer.com/ was more straightforward. It costs money, but it was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

My export contained multiple files with problematic file names: (exiftool does not find these files)

- IMG-20191102-WA0011(1).jpg
- IMG-20191102-WA0011.jpg(1).json

The json file should actually be:

- IMG-20191102-WA0011(1).jpg
- IMG-20191102-WA0011(1).jpg.json

The following script generates correct files and calls exiftool afterwards:

https://github.com/jeroendoggen/scripts-tools-misc/blob/master/jsonmerge/json_merge.py

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing here what I ended up using

https://gist.github.com/tetebueno/5800504133709c9844bcd1779019d390

The ONLY case this code can't address is when the file has a very long name (more than 46 characters (?)) and has one of the auto-photos suffix (`-edited`, etc.), because this ends up with something like:

```
very_large_file_name_..._foo-edited.jpg -> very_large_file_name_..._foo-edi.json
```