# I want to combine json and jpg files from Google Takeout

Tags: json, backup, jpeg, google-photos, exiftool

So, my Google Photos space exceeded 15gb. What I did was download all my Google Photos using Google Takeout. Now, I tried to extract one file using 7zip and found out I have several folders with JSON and jpg files. I decided to extract all of the export downloads into one single Folder. So I now have a folder with all the jpg and JSON files, but **I do not know how to combine a JSON file with its corresponding jpg file**. I tried searching a bit and found out Exiftool does the job. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914024) tells me how to do it for a bulk of files, but the answer involves some commands which I do not understand at all. I am not a tech guy. I just want to combine all my JSON and jpg files to back up my Google Photos and free up space to save money man. Please help. I need a fix to this desperately.

Comment: Probably this problem has already a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024255/bulk-join-json-with-jpg-from-google-takeout).